# How to call gen2 Cloud Function, that requires authentication, from CloudBuild step

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I created a gen 2 Cloud Function, added a role `Cloud Run Invoker` to cloud build default service account, calling the function following way:

```
gcloud functions call <func name> --region europe-central2 --gen2 --data "$(<payload.json)"
```

I'm getting following error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (HTTPError): 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url <func url>
```

Also tried the following:

- using curl and that was totally a no-go due to the inability to generate an identity token for cloud build service account:

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```

returns:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.print-identity-token) No identity token can be obtained from the current credentials
```

- using curl to call google metadata to obtain the token:

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=<func url> -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

returns: `Not Found`

- using gcloud print identity with impersonate:

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token --impersonate-service-account="xxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" --audiences="https://fun-url.a.run.app" --include-email
```

returns:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.print-identity-token) Failed to impersonate [xxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com]. Make sure the account that's trying to impersonate it has access to the service account itself and the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

Cloud build SA has `Service Account Token Creator` role.

Is it possible to call cloud functions from cloud build w. authentication?

Comment: I had difficulties to do similar things with Google Drive and I wrote and article on that. The key is to impersonate the Cloud Build service account to generate a usable token. https://medium.com/google-cloud/access-to-google-workspace-documents-from-cloud-build-3001c2883b66?source=user_profile---------4----------------------------

Answer (score 1):

First off, I do have a question to clarify things a bit more. Is there a particular reason you need to call the Cloud Function directly from Cloud Build? That will clear up the use case and might give us a better direction on what trigger to use.

I'm actually going to provide an alternative solution. I'd recommend using an [Eventarc Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/eventarc) instead to invoke your Cloud Function. You can then call that Eventarc trigger from Cloud Build instead which will be a lot easier. That way you can avoid this whole problem and still be secure via authentication.

While it does add an extra step, I'm recommending using more official ways of invoking your Cloud Function since it's safer to steer away from using the gcloud functions call. As mentioned by [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/call) this method has a very limited quota. So you'll need to use another trigger anyways in production.

> Note that this method has a limited quota which cannot be increased. It is intended for testing and debugging and should not be used in production.